# How to trigger a broadcast receiver from notification?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to trigger a Broadcast receiver from the notification. When I click on a button which is on the notification it shows this error:

> "Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.testservice.myBroad:
> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.testservice.myBroad cannot
> be cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver"

**updated/ edited and its working now **

1. Can you please help to handle 2 buttons from notification to broadcast receiver?
   How can I pass extra value from notification broadcast trigger to a receiver that whether its play button pressed or pause?
2. Now my button working but when I click on notification text it does not take me into my activity. Any help?

I write this code for 2 buttons with extra on intent.

```
 RemoteViews layout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
            layout.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, getString(R.string.app_name));
            Intent clickIntent = new Intent();
            clickIntent.putExtra("button","pause");
            clickIntent.setAction(ACTION_DIALOG);
           
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), pendingRequestCode, clickIntent, pendingFlag);
            layout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_button,pendingIntent);
            builder.setContent(layout);
            
            
             layout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
            layout.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, getString(R.string.app_name));
            Intent click = new Intent();
            clickIntent.putExtra("Button","play");
            clickIntent.setAction(ACTION_DIALOG);
           
            PendingIntent pi1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), pendingRequestCode, click, pendingFlag);
            layout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_button1,pi1);
            builder.setContent(layout);
```

myBroad receiver file

```
Bundle extrasBundle = intent.getExtras();
    String str = (String) extrasBundle.get("button");       
    Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    context.stopService(new Intent(context, myPlayService.class));
```

Here is my code:

```
void showNotification() {
     int pendingRequestCode = 0;
        int pendingFlag = 0;

        final Resources res = getResources();
        final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,myBroad.class);
        PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setTicker("this is notification")
                .setContentIntent(getDialogPendingIntent("Tapped the notification entry."));

        
            // Sets a custom content view for the notification, including an image button.
            RemoteViews layout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
            layout.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, getString(R.string.app_name));
            Intent clickIntent = new Intent();
            clickIntent.setAction(ACTION_DIALOG);
           
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), pendingRequestCode, clickIntent, pendingFlag);
            layout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_button,pendingIntent);
            builder.setContent(layout);

            // Notifications in Android 3.0 now have a standard mechanism for displaying large
            // bitmaps such as contact avatars. Here, we load an example image and resize it to the
            // appropriate size for large bitmaps in notifications.
            Bitmap largeIconTemp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,
                    R.drawable.notification_default_largeicon);
            Bitmap largeIcon = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                    largeIconTemp,
                    res.getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width),
                    res.getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height),
                    false);
            largeIconTemp.recycle();

            builder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_DEFAULT, builder.getNotification());
 }
    

    PendingIntent getDialogPendingIntent(String dialogText) {
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                dialogText.hashCode(), // Otherwise previous PendingIntents with the same
                                       // requestCode may be overwritten.
                new Intent(ACTION_DIALOG)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dialogText)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK),
                0);
    }
```

myBroad.class

```
public class myBroad extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(context, "received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
        context.stopService(new Intent(context, myPlayService.class));  
    }
}
```

Manifest file is:

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
          </activity>
          
     <receiver android:name=".myBroad">
        <intent-filter >
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
    </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
  
    <service android:name="com.example.testservice.myPlayService" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search" android:label="@string/app_name" android:enabled="true"/>
    
    
</application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because myBroad is an activity object, and not a broadcast object...

Instead of extending (inheritance) from activity, and then making an internal class which extends broadcastreceiver, then just inherit directly from broadcastreceiver.

Comment: can you help .. i want to pause music from service when i press this notification button..can you guide me. 
how can i access service method when i receive broadcast receiver

Answer (score 1):

In your method `getDialogPendingIntent` you should use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` instead of `PendingIntent.getActivity`. This will cause your `PendingIntent` to push a **broadcast**.

And fix this:

`public class myBroad extends BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: it work not after creating extend by broadcastreciver
can you help..i want to pause music from service when i press this notification button..can you guide me. how can i access service method when i receive broadcast receiver

Comment: How can i recognized in broadcast receiver that whether its pause button pressed or play button. also when i pressed on notification text it does not take me into activity..any help

Comment: First decide, either you want to broadcast or show an activity when a notification is selected. Second, you may add optional data in your intent's bundle to identify the command action you want to perform at the receiving end

Comment: see I want both , like having media player controls on notification in which you can pause play audio and when you click on text part of notification you redirect into activity .. to achieve this I used broadcast receiver to take button pressed or not and according to that i stopservice from receiver.. i want to use 2 button on notification for pause and play..

Comment: I have updated the main question with code for 2 button with intent extra and receiver but on notification i am not able to click on these 2 buttons

Comment: You shouldn't update the question with that, since the question is not matching the topic now. Revert it please and make a new question with the specific details needed.

Answer (score 0):

Exception says it clearly - your `myBroad` have to extend `BroadcastReceiver`, not `Activity` as it does now.

PS: you should consider switching to proper naming convenction. So it should be `MyBroad` (class) but `myBroad` (object of that class). i.e.:

```
MyBroad myBroad = new MyBroad();
```

Comment: can you help .. i want to pause music from service when i press this notification button..can you guide me. how can i access service method when i receive broadcast receiver

Comment: How can i recognized in broadcast receiver that whether its pause button pressed or play button. also when i pressed on notification text it does not take me into activity..any help